# get notified when a ColdFusion web app is installed on a new server

Tags: coldfusion

A company wants to take over maintaining a ColdFusion web app that was developed for them. They want to install on their server, which should be fine. However, they shouldn't be selling this app to other companies.

How can I set up a notification that gets sent to me every time it's installed on a new server. Keep in mind that they will have access to the code.

Comment: If the company takes over maintaining a web app that they paid for to be built for them, it is their property. They bought it; they own it. Unless you had a contractual agreement for them not to sell the app to third parties, they are within their right to do so.

Comment: I was working for a company that had software developed by a third party, I would make sure that it didn't send out any unauthorized notifications to the third party. I have worked on sites that have a high expectation of confidentiality. We don't even use CDNs because that might give away some confidential info [sic]. This is a dead end for all kinds of reasons.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- They contracted your company to create the application for them.
- They contracted your company to maintain the application and servers.
- They contracted your company to perform updates and build new features.
- Now they want to maintain the application and servers.
- They want to deploy multiple copies of the application for their clients.
- They may still have your company perform updates and build new features.

Guess what? You never owned the code.

- They paid for it.
- They own it.
- They can do whatever they want with it.

Unless your company built the application on their own dime and licensed it to the other company, you have no ground to stand on.